# Avoid becoming victim of database deadlock

Tags: sql-server, database, deadlock

Everyday day I run a sql server script to update my table.  Once a week I become a victim of a database deadlock. Several people have access to the database and they all know they are not supposed to access the database while it is updating. But someone is accessing the database during the update and we have deadlock. Is there a way I can avoid becoming a victim of deadlock? I’ve heard of deadlock priority. Will it help if I set the deadlock priority to 10? Are there any performance issue or consequences  for using deadlock priority?

Comment: Exclusively lock the DB before you start your processes. this will keep it so you don't encounter the deadlock MSFT article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519(v=sql.105).aspx  Just be sure to clear the lock when done or on a fail!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the other processes have a deadlock priority less than 10, this should cause you to win the deadlock resolution.

> If the sessions have different deadlock priorities, the session with the lowest deadlock priority is chosen as the deadlock victim.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186736.aspx

Of course you could always run a script removing update rights from other users for the duration of your update...

Comment: Most likeLY they won't have any deadlock priority set and no one has the rights to update anything in the database. They only have read only access. Are there any drawback for using deadlock priority?

Comment: @LitonUddin: If they do not update data, you could consider whether they could use the READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level.  That may be appropriate for their task (depending on exactly what they are reading and the nature of your updates), and a clean solution to avoid deadlocks.  I'm not aware of a down side of using DEADLOCK PRIORITY if used correctly.  If multiple teams all think they should have the highest priority of course, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Several people have access to the database and they all know they are
>   not supposed to access the database while it is updating

Why dont you just put the DB in Single User, do your update and the revert to multi user in one single transaction?

Raj